# Comments custom CSS

Tags: css, facebook-comments

I am trying to have the Facebook comments on my site, and I would like to style it to match my sites design. Is it possible to include custom CSS to the comments, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: If you're asking how to style content coming from Facebook, you can't.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the comments coming from facebook... the <fb:fan > allows for a css= attribute that will allow you to include custom stylesheet. I was wondering if comments had a similar function.

Comment: It does not. If it did, it would be [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per *[Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)*, you get two styling options, dark or light. There is no way for you to specify your own CSS.